Yang-Mills action is invariant under conformal change of the metric
Let $(M,g)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian 4-manifold with a principal bundle $P\to M$. Prove that the Yang–Mills action $S_{YM}[A]$ is invariant under a conformal change of the metric $g$: $\quad g'=\mathrm{e}^{2\lambda}g$, where $\lambda\in \mathscr{C}^{\infty}(M)$.
By definition, the Yang–Mills action for a principal bundle $P\to M$ is a smooth map
$$
S_{YM}: \mathscr{A}(P)\to \mathbb{R}
$$
defined by
$$
S_{YM}[A]=-\frac{1}{2}\int_M\langle F_M^A,F_M^A\rangle_{\mathrm{Ad}(P)}\operatorname{dvol}_g
$$
My calculation is as follows.
Take the local coordinate $\{x_k\}$ on $M$. We write the volume form $\mathrm{dvol}_{g'}=\sqrt{\mathrm{det}g'}\ \mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_2\wedge\mathrm{d}x_3\wedge\mathrm{d}x_4=\mathrm{e}^{4\lambda}\sqrt{\mathrm{det}g}\ \mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_2\wedge\mathrm{d}x_3\wedge\mathrm{d}x_4$, and the curvature $F_M^A$ can be expressed locally as $F_M^{Aa}\otimes T_a$, then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S_{YM}^{g'}[A]&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_MF^{Aa}_M(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu})F^{Ab}_M(\partial_{\upsilon},\partial_{\kappa})g'(T_a,T_b)\operatorname{dvol}_{g'}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_MF^{Aa}_M(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu})F^{Ab}_M(\partial_{\upsilon},\partial_{\kappa})\mathrm{e}^{4\lambda}g(T_a,T_b)\mathrm{e}^{4\lambda}\operatorname{dvol}_{g}\\
&=\mathrm{e}^{8\lambda}S_{YM}^{g}[A]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
There must be something wrong, because I think it should have implied $\mathrm{e}^{-4\lambda}$ from the local expression of $F_M^A$ to kill the $\mathrm{e}^{4\lambda}$ term derived from the volume form. But I can't find the error.

The curvature is a 2-form, so you use the inverse metric.
$$g(\mathrm dx^i, \mathrm dx^j) = g^{ij}$$
which carries the opposite conformal factor as $g_{ij}$.
So in $n$ dimensions, write $F = F_{ij}\mathrm dx^i\wedge \mathrm dx^j$ and use $\tilde g =  f^2g$:
$$\begin{align*}
S_{YM} &=\int_M |F|^2 ~\mathrm dv_{\tilde g}\\
&= \int \langle F_{ij},F_{kl}\rangle \tilde{g}^{ik}\tilde{g}^{jl} \sqrt{\det \tilde g}~ \mathrm dx \\
&= \int \langle F_{ij},F_{kl}\rangle f^{-4}g^{ik}g^{jl} f^{n}\sqrt{\det g}~ \mathrm dx \\
&= \int f^{n-4} |F|^2 ~\mathrm dv_g \\
\end{align*}$$

You have a point, thank you!
